# How to draw set inclusion diagram (picture in body)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

How does one tikz this? I'm not entirely sure what its called.

Edit: I care not so much about this diagram in particular, but these types of diagrams.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I literally have no clue how to tex much of anything.

Comment: There is a clue for you `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse(.6 and .25);
\path (0,0) node{$\mathbb{N}$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks; I'll try to piece it together

Comment: 2nd clue: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf and 3rd clue http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8,4)
    \foreach \x/\s/\l in {4.0/1.0/R,3.6/0.8/Q,3.2/0.6/Z,2.8/0.4/N}
    {\rput(\x,2){\psset{unit=\s}\psellipse(0,0)(4,2)\rput(3,0){$\mathbb{\l}$}}}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]